# Is it possible to add a url scheme to an already installed app?

Tags: ios, url, dictionary, url-scheme

Let me explain what i want to do first:
I have an ipad and i installed a cydia tweak that adds search engines to the notification center, i want to search from the apps already installed. It worked for the IMDb application using the following url scheme:

```
imdb:///find?q=%@
```

Where %@ is the inserted word
Unfortunately there is no such url scheme for the Dictionary app, is it possible to add a url scheme to it to search for a word directly from that tweak.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not possible to add a URI scheme for installed application. Please check the [Wiki Page](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)  for some custom URI schemes.